# Which is more commonly used in writing? 者 or もん

Tags: kanji, quotes

Which is more commonly used in writing? 者 or もん.

For example:

1. 笑った者勝ち
2. 笑ったもん勝ち

Comment: I'm confused what 笑ったもん勝ち is supposed to mean.  Do you mean something like, "The one who laughs is the winner"?  What's the context in which this is being said?

Comment: And, how is this different from your earlier question from today?

Comment: I'm just curious what's more commonly used to construct this sentence, 者 or もん.

Answer (score 2):

In general, もん is highly colloquial, and should be avoided in formal writings. もん may be fine in casual personal blogs, but it's out of the question in news articles, Wikipedia articles and such. Even in casual writing, もん sounds a bit rough, and many people choose to use 人 instead.

However, this ～もん勝ち ("the one who does ～ is the winner") is an exception because it is an established set phrase. It's fine to say 逃げたもん勝ち ("fleeing is winning") even in a serious essay. I personally feel もん is more common in this set phrase, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[BCCWJ](https://bonten.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/string_search?commit=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2&string_search%5Bgenres%5D=PN_core%2CPN%2CPM_core%2CPM%2CPB_core%2CPB%2CLB_core%2CLB%2COW%2COB%2COC_core%2COC%2COY_core%2COY%2COL%2COM%2COP%2COT%2COV&string_search%5Bwords%5D=%E8%80%85%E5%8B%9D%E3%81%A1&string_search%5Byears%5D=1971%2C1972%2C1973%2C1974%2C1975%2C1976%2C1977%2C1978%2C1979%2C1980%2C1981%2C1982%2C1983%2C1984%2C1985%2C1986%2C1987%2C1988%2C1989%2C1990%2C1991%2C1992%2C1993%2C1994%2C1995%2C1996%2C1997%2C1998%2C1999%2C2000%2C2001%2C2002%2C2003%2C2004%2C2005%2C2006%2C2007%2C2008&utf8=%E2%9C%93) returns: 45 examples for 者勝ち vs 17 examples for both もの勝ち and もん勝ち.

For writing, 者勝ち seems more common as suggested by the corpus, but it could be only that we type that way　(e.g. when I type 早い者勝ち below, it is suggested by the input method as I typed はやい). Since もん is an easier-to-pronounce version of 者, it does not exactly make sense to compare them in writing.

My personal impression is that, for more idiomatic phrases like 早い者勝ち, 者 and もん sounds equally natural, but for less common ones like 笑ったもん勝ち, もん sounds natural (or smoother) possibly because they are used in written form less frequently.

Comment: 質問は一般的な「もん」と「者」の使い分けについてであり、「～勝ち」はあくまで例として挙げられているに過ぎないように思います